# Rails render subaction gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my problem with Rails.

Sometimes there is independent blocks at the page (e.g. "Latest news") which has no logical relation to current controller or action. In regular rails MVC stack I would write `@news = News.latest` in my controller and `render 'shared/latest_news', news: @news` in my view.
However its too much for me for several reasons. Instead I want to write `render 'shared/latest_news', locals_call: "NewsController#latest"` in view and that's it.
What should happen behind this row is calling "NewsController#latest" method to receive a hash of locals used in rendering this template.

Does anyone know gem for such calls?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a universal helper method in ApplicationHelper:

```
def latest_news_tag
  render partial: 'shared/latest_news', locals: { news: News.latest }
end
```

You can call this method in any view you want, e.g. `<%= latest_news_tag %>`.